# mysql update multiple tables with single sql to get sum(qty)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with data

```
CREATE TABLE `MASTER` (
  `NAME` VARCHAR(10)      NOT NULL,
  `QTY`  INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NAME`)
);
NAME  | QTY
----------
'ABC' | 0
'XYZ' | 0
CREATE TABLE `DETAIL` (
  `NAME` VARCHAR(10)         NOT NULL,
  `QTY`  INT(10) UNSIGNED    NOT NULL,
  `FLAG` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);
NAME  | QTY| FLAG
--------------------
'ABC' | 10 | 0
'ABC' | 20 | 0
'PQR' | 15 | 0
'PQR' | 25 | 0
```

i want to update sum(detail.qty) to master and set its flag to 1
so i have written query

```
UPDATE MASTER M, DETAIL D
SET M.QTY = M.QTY + D.QTY,
  D.FLAG =1
WHERE M.NAME = D.NAME;
```

i have guesed MASTER.QTY should be 30 (10 + 20) from detail table.
but it only updates the first value 
actual value is MASTER.QTY =10 (only updtaed first value from table)

How can i get MASTER.QTY =30?

Comment: How many rows do you expect to have in the DETAIL table?

Comment: I agree that the master table is probably unecessary (this could be a view). But your other table requires a PK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
update `MASTER` m,`DETAIL` d,
(
   SELECT `NAME`, SUM( `QTY` ) as `QTY`
   FROM `DETAIL`
   GROUP BY `NAME`
) s
SET m.QTY = s.QTY,
    d.FLAG = 1
WHERE
    m.NAME = s.NAME
    AND m.NAME = d.NAME
;
```

SQLFiddle demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab355/1

Answer (score 0):

IMO, your Master table is unnecessary. You don't need it if the amount of rows ain't in a > 5-digit range.

This equals the MASTER table:

```
SELECT NAME, SUM(QTY), FLAG FROM DETAIL GROUP BY NAME;
```

You can create a view from that easily.

Your answer anyways:

```
UPDATE MASTER m
JOIN DETAIL d ON m.NAME = d.NAME
SET
  d.FLAG = 1,
  m.QTY = (SELECT SUM(QTY) FROM DETAIL WHERE NAME = d.NAME GROUP BY NAME)
WHERE m.NAME = d.NAME
```

Also, always follow normalization rules: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization